# Marionette View automatically listen to Bootstrap events of child elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, marionette

I have a marionette view that encapsulates a Bootstrap tab panel.

I know I can do the following to listen for events,

```
$("#mytab").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   //do my thing
})
```

but I would really like to be able to have marionette automatically capture events and handle deregistering the listener through its event system:

```
Tabs = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:tabsTemplate,
    events:{
        "shown.bs.tab #mytab":function(){console.log("tab opened~")}
    },
   ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have a look at http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.behaviors.html

Comment: @nikhilmehta I haven't seen these before, but they seem to only work with the same Marionette view events; I couldn't find where in their docs for the Behavior/Behaviors classes where to set up the listener/binding. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Behaviors have events that are bound to the views DOM." The View DOM binding is exactly where I'm unsuccessfully trying to get the events; if I could get them in the View, I could abstract them to the Behavior. --- That being said I am definitely going to start using these now, regardless